# What's the preferred way of exiting a command line program?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

This should be straightforward. I just need to simply exit my commandline c# program - no fancy stuff.

Should I use

```
Environment.Exit();
```

or

```
this.Close();
```

or something else?

Comment: `this.Close` won't even work in a console app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `return;` in your `Main` method.
If you aren't in the main method when you decide to exit the program, you need to return from the method that Main method currently executes.

Example:

```
void Main(...)
{
    DisplayAvailableCommands();
    ProcessCommands();
}

void ProcessCommands()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var command = ReadCommandFromConsole();
        switch(command)
        {
            case "help":
                DisplayHelp();
                break;
            case "exit":
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not really an example of good overall design of a console application, but it illustrates the point.

Comment: I want to call exit from outside the Main method.

Comment: accepting because first answerer and i ended up using return.

Answer (score 18):

just return from the `Main` method.

**Edit:**

if you really have lost the flow and want to exit from anywhere in the application (like inside any method called by Main), you can use:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

remember that normally you should return 0 to the calling process (OS) when everything went fine and you return a non zero value if an error happened and execution did not go as smooth as should have been.

Comment: I want to call exit from outside the Main method.

Comment: are you inside a method called from main? can't you return to main and main returns as well.

Comment: great answer but slightly after other answer -also i used return