# preferred way of exiting a command line program - part 2

Tags: c#

I tried to edit this question: [What's the preferred way of exiting a command line program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403900/c-sharp-preferred-way-of-exiting-a-command-line-program)

But my edit was rejected. I'm not allowed to comment, hence I'll take the risk of duplicating the question.

The original question was "What is the best way to exit a command line program". The best way is obviously to `return` from `Main()`, but what if I want to exit from an event handler like `Console.CancelKeyPress` or a Timer?

Is the only way to exit "far away" from Main(), like in an event handler, the `Environment.Exit()` method? It's possibly unsafe because `Environment.Exit()` will not clean up.

Example code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer(4000);
        t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
        t.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    static void t_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I want to exit here
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is a new question, it should clearly not be edited into an old question that people are unlikely to watch for updates.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: if the exit code actually matters and someone may try to actually use it, you'll want to use either `Environment.Exit()` or you need to update your Main() to return an int (the value being the status code you want to return to the OS). so really, it depends.

Comment: So if I need to clean up, I should never exit (the program) in an event handler? Yeah, that's probably the answer. My question was more like: Is there a "secret way" to get Main() to return? :-)

Comment: Is your Main in a processing loop?  Maybe you could set an Event or flag in the handler/timer that the loop could check the state of and then exit the loop cleanly.

Comment: BTW: Why was this question down-voted? Although the solution was simple.

Comment: You can't edit a question that isn't yours when you lack sufficient rep to edit questions. You also should not be trying to edit other people's questions to make them your own.

Comment: It is quite fun to see the score -3 on this question. ”The question does now show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful”. It is definitely not unclear; Exit inside an event handler. Lack of research effort? Well, it’s still unanswered, and I’m still (re)searching… Say no more.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Providing your program is single-threaded, you can throw a custom exception, and catch it no soner than in the `Main()` method. That gives you plenty of opportunities to perform any cleanup (e.g. in `finally` blocks) to achieve graceful exit. Like this:

```
public class ExitProgramException : Exception { }

public void SomeNestedStuff()
{
    ...
    if (...) throw new ExitProgramException();
    ...
}

public void Main()
{
    try 
    {
        ...
        SomeNestedStuff();
        ...
    }
    catch (ExitProgramException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bye!");
    }
}
```

However, if your program is multi-threaded, then you will need to implement some more complex graceful exit mechanism, depending on the specifics of your business logic.

Comment: But again, this will not work in an event handler, right? You cannot throw an exception in an event handler and catch it in Main() ?

Comment: The handler of `Console.CancelKeyPress` runs on a thread-pool thread. It designed to follow its own mechanism for aborting the application. You should read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That means the question is unanswered.